# java - How to use invokeLater to synchronize some IO with UI

Tags: java, swing, invokelater

In my java application I am using swing to implement the UI. There is a button called **theButton**  which is engaged with some IO operation in the following timely steps :

1. the button originally has the text "Click to connect"
2. then before the connect operation starts I want the **theButton**  reads
   "Connecting in progress..."
3. then the IO operation gets started
4. once the IO operation is done **theButton** now reads "connected ( click to disconnect)".

   - **Issue**:
   - I am using the following code, but first of all the button's text doesn't change to "Connecting in progress..." before the IO starts! as well button doenst actually get disabled before the IO starts! What should I do here?

--

```
// theButton with text "Click to connect is clicked"
javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
theButton.setText("Trying to connect...");
theButton.setEnabled(false);// to avoid clicking several times! Some users cannot wait
theButton.repaint();
// doing some IO operation which takes few seconds
theButton.setText("connected ( click to disconnect)");
theButton.setEnabled(true);
theButton.repaint();
}
});
```

Comment: Background Workers and asynchronous events.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is here:

```
javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    theButton.setText("Trying to connect...");
    theButton.setEnabled(false);
    theButton.repaint();

    // doing some IO operation which takes few seconds // **********

    theButton.setText("connected ( click to disconnect)");
    theButton.setEnabled(true);
    theButton.repaint();
  }
});
```

- The code marked with the `*******` comment is running on the EDT and will tie it up freezing your app and all it's painting.
- Use a SwingWorker instead to run the code in a background thread.
- Note that there is no need to use `invokeLater(...)` for code in an ActionListener since this code is already running on the EDT by default.
- Also get rid of your `repaint()` calls since they aren't needed and they don't help.
- Add a PropertyChangeListener to your SwingWorker to listen for when it is done, and then you can reset your JButton.

Instead do:

```
// code not compiled nor tested
javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    theButton.setText("Trying to connect...");
    theButton.setEnabled(false);

    MySwingWorker mySwingWorker = new MySwingWorker();

    mySwingWorker.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
      // listen for when SwingWorker's state is done
      // and reset your button.
      public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent pcEvt) {
        if (pcEvt.getNewValue() == SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE) {
          theButton.setText("connected ( click to disconnect)");
          theButton.setEnabled(true);
        }
      }
    });

    mySwingWorker.execute();
  }
});
```

and

```
// code not compiled nor tested
public class MySwingWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {
  @Override
  public void doInBackground() throws Exception {
    // doing some IO operation which takes few seconds
    return null;
  }
}
```

And be sure to read: [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html).

Comment: Although, I'm sort of curious why the repaint didn't update the UI before the "freeze" (even if I recommend against this approach in general). I thought repaint was immediate - or there was another similar hack to force a UI update? - for this particular sort of hackish case ..

Comment: @user2246674: the repaint won't work because when you call it, you queue up a repaint request on the repaint manager queue. The manager won't have time to process the request before the long-running process ties up your EDT.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Ahh, right, that's what the hack was .. `invokeLater(doBeforeBlockingWorkAndQueueRepaintAndQueueInvokeLaterForBlockingOperation);` *shudder*.

Comment: @user2246674: The solution is to use a SwingWorker, not a hack. :)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yes, indeed :D http://stackoverflow.com/a/13477171/2246674 - wrt. repaint and EDT (not for you, but a good read that also points out the dubious nature of such a `repaint` approach that seems useful to be associated)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks a lot. the only issue is that I dont know where to place the catch block to catch the IOException of public Void doInBackground() throws Exception. Any tip please? Placing it around  mySwingWorker.execute(); will not work

Comment: @Cgraphics: You can place it around the SwingWorker's `get()` method.

Comment: Means replacing mySwingWorker.execute() with mySwingWorker.get()?

Comment: @Cgraphics: no, the `execute()` is needed to start the SwingWorker's background thread. The `get()` would be called after the SwingWorker finishes, such as in the PropertyChangeListener. Please be sure to read the tutorial that I've linked to above as well as the SwingWorker tutorial.